# PHP TypeError: Parameter must be an instance of lib\util\mixed, string given

Tags: php, types, typeerror, mixed

In my PHP file I have created a function with a parameter which can be of any type. Because of this, I declared this parameter as `mixed`. It seems the `mixed` type is linked to the folder location where the class is headed; `lib\util`. The error says  `instance of lib\util\mixed`.

```
protected function curlSetOpt(int $param1, mixed $param2): bool
{
    return anotherFunction($this->variable, $param1, $param2);
}
```

The moment I call this method using a string, a TypeError occurs.

> Argument 2 passed to lib\util\Class::function() must be an instance of lib\util\mixed, string given

Renaming the type from `mixed` to `string` works, but also other types are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mixed` is not a valid type for hinting in PHP. The valid types are listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

The slightly cryptic error message is because PHP is assuming you are trying to restrict the type to a class within your namespace: `lib\util\mixed`.

If you don't want to restrict the type, just don't add a type hint.

Comment: You are right, just wanted to mention that. `mixed` should only be defined within the PHPDoc above the function. Not within the declaration itself. You are not forcing to let the parameter be of some specific type. It can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Although Simon's answer above is right at the time of question i just want to add that since php 8.0 it is supported:
https://php.watch/versions/8.0/mixed-type